# How do I setup Connection Strings for a WebJob project?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

I am trying to setup a website and webjob, but get an error everytime I try to publish the webjob independently of the website (i.e. Selecting `Publish as Azure WebJob` from the context menu)

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4270,5):
>   Error : The 'MyWebJob.Models.MyDataEntities-Web.config Connection
>   String' argument cannot be null or empty.
>   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4270,5):
>   Error : The 'MyWebJob.Models.MoreDataEntities-Web.config Connection
>   String' argument cannot be null or empty.

There are two options for deploying a WebJob

- [Deploy with a website project](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-deploy-webjobs/#convertlink)
- [Deploy the webjob independently](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-deploy-webjobs/#convertnolink)

When I link my webjob to a website project, it deploys with the website without error. However, when I try to deploy it independently I get the above error in my console and Error List, but the webjob is still deployed.

How can I deploy my webjob independently and get rid of this persistent "error"?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the publish profile file and re-publishing?

Comment: I have the same problem, and deleting and republish doesn't change it

Comment: @l19 Many times, because the error only disappears after you delete the publish profile and clean.

Comment: More answers can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580680/vs2010-web-deploy-the-connection-string-argument-cannot-be-null-or-empty

Answer (score 48):

I found that providing a value for

```
 <Destination Path="" />
```

in your publish profile pubxml file got rid of the issue.  This can usually be found in \Properties\PublishProfiles.  You probably have something like:

```
<PublishDatabaseSettings>
  <Objects xmlns="">
    <ObjectGroup Name="Context" Order="1" Enabled="False">
      <Destination Path="" />
      <Object Type="DbCodeFirst">
        <Source Path="DBMigration" DbContext="Context, DAO" MigrationConfiguration="Context.Migrations.Configuration, DAO" Origin="Convention" />
      </Object>
    </ObjectGroup>
  </Objects>
</PublishDatabaseSettings>
```

Changing it to the following fixed it for me:

```
<PublishDatabaseSettings>
  <Objects xmlns="">
    <ObjectGroup Name="Context" Order="1" Enabled="False">
      <Destination Path="{deployment connection string}" />
      <Object Type="DbCodeFirst">
        <Source Path="DBMigration" DbContext="Context, DAO" MigrationConfiguration="Context.Migrations.Configuration, DAO" Origin="Convention" />
      </Object>
    </ObjectGroup>
  </Objects>
</PublishDatabaseSettings>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This works for me sometimes. I have a project with multiple profiles. It worked for one but not the other.

Comment: Ok, it seems to work if you restart Visual Studio after changing the pubxml file.

Comment: I can confirm that this worked for me also, but do we have any idea what caused the problem?

Comment: what exactly should i write into {deployment connection string}. currently my visual studio instance crashes while trying to deploy the webjob...

Comment: @jrummell is correct in reloading project after making changes works.  You can also "unload" the project and load it again which is quicker than closing and restarting VS.

Comment: @skorzinetzki I literally put the letter `s` there and it started working.  What a shit process.

Comment: The given answer above doesn't tell us what to enter here, unless we indeed want to stinking duplicate our full connection string in every webjobs stupid profile. So I want to reiterate @SB2055 's point above, I entered simply the letter 'z' like follows: `<Destination Path="z" />` and that seems to work. And yes, this is ridiculous. I wouldn't complain, if it was not for the fact this situation has existed for so long; outside of webjobs, every web publish tries to force you to fill out your connection strings and I have to manually remove them, I do connection strings dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

I found that deleting the `obj` directory within the WebJob project will clear the staging area in which the WebJob package to be published is being built. Publish was then successful.

Answer (score 1):

**Reason of the problem** 
Change the name of the connection string in the Web.Config or/and adding a new connection string to the Web.Config.

**Solution**

1. Select the website project, right click on it, and click publish.

   ---

   [image]

---

2. Press the settings link and from the pop-up window select the 'Settings' Tab
3. Uncheck the `use this connection string at runtime` from all your connection strings.

[image]

4. Click `Save` button to close the the window. (No need to Restart Visual Studio)
5. Try to publish the website again, and it should publish without problem.

**NOTE** 
I am using VS 2017

**Just for Note** 
After I did the previous steps, I noticed that the .pubxml file changed automatically. here is the difference which has been made (automatically without any interference from me)

So I think this is better way because it is easier for developer and also it let the visual studio to solve its problems himself, without forcing it for specific thing.

[image]